# Lebesuge integrable function always bounded?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Assume $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue integrable, does it imply that $f$ is bounded almost surly?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is not bounded but its integrable: $\int_0^1\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\, dx=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so..

Look for example at $\frac1{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$.